# Focus issue while Enter Key press using React-data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-data-grid

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-shirley-88jwkj?file=/src/App.js:0-3588

Here I use MUI for Styling and Reactdatagrid.

In here when we are on last column that time if we press Enter our focus will be go to the next row's first column. But it throw error.

Focus on Next row's first column while we press Enter key.